# docker0 networking in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker network questions, consider the following:

```
#docker network create --driver macvlan \
  --subnet=1.2.3.0/24 \
  --gateway=1.2.3.1 \
  -o parent=eth2 \
  untrust

# cat /opt/docker-compose.yml
version: "3.5"
services:
  foo:
    container_name: foo
    image: foo/foo-agent:latest
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 1.2.3.4

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: untrust

# docker inspect foo

...
            "Networks": {
                "untrust": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "1.2.3.4"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "8f8cd42eb471"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "a0720868f1c9178bf0ac4e104076a0c2a318acf93c885319a7a5599c52a15992",
                    "EndpointID": "bb73157ed0b2376a7b002787388de8d2bed03eaabd995684eb06a66303d47620",
                    "Gateway": "1.2.3.1",
                    "IPAddress": "1.2.3.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:d0:76:e1:65",
                    "DriverOpts": null
    ...
```

The default driver in docker-compose has been replaced with macvlan driver. Does this mean app foo will no longer has access to docker0 bridge?

We are deploying an application in the dmz and want to make sure it can only listen on eth2.

Comment: Setting `ports:` to only listen on specific host IP addresses (or potentially removing `ports:` entitrely) will probably be easier, if you're just trying to control inbound connections to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default driver in docker-compose has been replaced with macvlan
> driver. Does this mean app foo will no longer has access to docker0
> bridge?

- when only attached to one network , the macvlan is "hard-wired" to your bridged interface , but for loop prevention you cannot communicate with the docker host, only other containers in that network
- to have "native" implementation ( e.g. ONE interface with ipv6 & ipv4 where you need to either have a container as router (.222 in the example ) or assign the ipv4 gateway ip to your host-side child interface , here "foobar"
- v6 gateway should be the ::1/NETMASK address, this address should be assigned to your host-side child interface , here "foobar", and you are fine ( **this way you can also have non-NAT-ed IPv6 in Docker containers**  )

```
#native macvlan access via child of eth42, docker network will be named ipv6
docker network create -d macvlan --gateway 192.168.123.222 --ip-range=192.168.123.128/25 --subnet=192.168.123.0/24 --aux-address='ip1=192.123.254.2' --aux-address='host=192.168.123.123' -o "com.docker.network.bridge.name=ipv6"  --ipv6 --subnet=2a01:d34d:beef::/48 --gateway 2a01:d34d:beef::1 -o macvlan_mode=bridge -o parent=eth42   ipv6
ifconfig eth42 up
ip link add foobar link eth42 type macvlan mode bridge
#ifconfig foobar
ifconfig foobar 192.168.123.222/24 up 
ip -6 a a 2a01:d34d:beef::1/48 dev foobar
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what my expectations. There is many questions around this topic but I couldn't find a common answer.

Comment: ( was a tough round for me as well to get it working , but yes , it is possible to circumvent docker's fake-magic .. in fact all containers attached to the same bridge see each other ,the same applies to macvlan )